# TypeMismatchError when try to use readAsText

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a text file when the page start but it results
TypeMismatchError for reader.readAsText(text.files[0]);

```
function mm(){
    var text=document.getElementById("aspect");
    const reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload= function(){
        //var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        console.log(reader.result);};
    reader.readAsText(text.files[0]);}
window.addEventListener("load",mm,false);    


<body>
    <input id="aspect" type="file" value="aspects.txt" style="display:none;" />
</body>
```

i expected to print the file contents but i got the error message

Comment: can you tell both files document character encoding?

Comment: @milchePatern UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `mm` when a file is selected not when the window loads, add a change event handler on the file input.

```
function mm(){
    var text=document.getElementById("aspect");
    const reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload= function(){
        //var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        console.log(reader.result);};
    reader.readAsText(text.files[0]);
}


<body>
    <input id="aspect" type="file" value="aspects.txt" onchange="mm()" style="display:none;" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would format like that (I've used it before):

```js
window.onload = function() {

    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("aspect");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

            var file = files[0];

                //Only plain text check
            if (!file.type.match('plain')) continue;

            var yourReader = new FileReader();

            yourReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

                var textFile = event.target;
                console.log(textFile.result);

            });

            //Read the text file
            yourReader.readAsText(file);

        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the `value` of an `input[type=file]` to an URL or an hard-coded file-name. You need to select it by using the OS file picker and for this, you need to click your <input>.

Currently, you were passing `undefined` to `FileReader.readAsText()`, hence the error:

```js
new FileReader().readAsText(undefined);
```

What you want is to handle the <input>'s change, or check at page load if it's being populated already (e.g after a page refresh in Firefox):

```js
function onpageload() {
  var text = document.getElementById("aspect");
  text.addEventListener('change', readFile);
  // if at page load we already have some file selected
  if (text.files.length) {
    readFile.call(text);
  }
  // we need a mean to click our input
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    text.click();
  });

}

function readFile(evt) {
  const text = this;
  console.log(text)
  const file = text.files[0];
  if(!file) return; // no file, no reader
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(text.files[0]);
}


window.addEventListener("load", onpageload, false);
```

```html
<input id="aspect" type="file" style="display:none;" />
<button id="button">select a file</button>
```

Comment: thanks I was looking for a way to do it without using the OS file picker
like when you use <img> tag you can add the src without using OS file picker
but it seems there is no way to do it